# How to create BitMap from FileUpload AllowMultiple set to true?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, uploading, allowmultiple

I want to create a bitmap of each file in FileUpload, AllowMultiple set to True, but it's not working. In single file mode, I used to get bitmap from FileUpload.FileContent and it was OK.

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in flImage.PostedFiles)
{
    Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(file);
```

Thanks for  your kind help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.InputStream` instead of `file`:

```
foreach (HttpPostedFile file in flImage.PostedFiles){
    Bitmap originalBMP = new Bitmap(file.InputStream);
}
```